# MS Access Null Reference when importing a table

Tags: ms-access

So I am very new to MS Access. I have two tables, one of which imports fine (importing from excel), the primary key I select has no issue. However, my second table always returns a "Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value." error whenever I choose the primary key. What am I missing?

The primary key for the first table which works is 'Product No.' and the one which returns the error is 'SupplierID' if you cannot tell I am very unfamiliar with databases and access. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might have to copy/paste the filled rows into a new Worksheet and try another import from the new sheet. Sometimes Excel will identify the UsedRange of rows to include a bunch of empty rows - usually after a bunch of deletes

Answer (score 0):

Some of your imported SupplierID are *Null* which a primary index cannot hold - as the message tells you.

So clean up your data before attempting an import.

Answer (score 0):

you must check that your field data type must match in both tables( primary key and foreign key) and excel